# EmberJS, Loading first object on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

Hopefully, a simple question and must have a simple answer but i have wasted almost 3hrs in getting out of this issue.

I have a user model. I want to load the first user from DB and show it on first page load.

What i am trying to use is:

in my ArrayController,

```
init: function(){
  var user = App.User.find(1)
  console.log(user);
   this.set('defualtUser',user.get('name'))
}
```

But i cant get the name of user.

Here is the output of user in console, which indicates that data is being loaded but i can't just get it to use.

```
Class
  __ember1367188634172: "ember270"
  __ember1367188634172_meta: Meta
  _changesToSync: Object
  _data: Object
    attributes: Object
    ***name: "Cafe Alpino"***
    __proto__: Object
    belongsTo: Object
    hasMany: Object
    id: null
    __proto__: Object
```

See the name: "Cafe Alpino", i just want to display this name.

Any help???

BTW, i am a newbie with EmberJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is asynchronousy. This line: `var user = App.User.find(1)` will result in a `user` record that is not loaded yet; its properties aren't set until the AJAX call returns in the background. Therefore, `user.get('name')` will be empty.

There are probably a few ways to solve this. I haven't used Ember Data too much (since it's not very solid at the moment), but according to [the docmentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/), there should be a `didLoad` event that you can use:

```
init: function() {
    var user = App.User.find(1);
    var _this = this;
    user.on('didLoad', function() {
        _this.set('defaultUser', user.get('name'));
    });
}
```

Give it a try! Let me know if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks man, worked for. I wonder, i actually tried this thing before posting this question.
But i was doing a mistake. this.set('defaultUser',test.get('store').get('name'));

Comment: assuming i don't want to hard code the user_id to 1 in App.User.find(1). how do i make the id passed to find to be dynamic, so that if a user with any type of id whether id 1 0r id 3 or id 55 is passed into find, it will not fail. any suggestions. thanks.

Comment: @brg you should take a look at the guides on emberjs.com. You can achieve this with a "dynamic segment" in your route: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments